# Jquery moving LI elements between unordered lists

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am playing with some jquery moving list items between 2 unordered lists and can kind of get it to work with both

```
$('#l2 li').click(function(){
  $('#l1).append($(this))
});
$('#l1 li').click(function(){
  $('#l2).append($(this))
});
```

and

```
 $('#l1 li').click(function(){
      $(this).detach().prependTo('#l2');
 });

 $('#l2 li').click(function(){
    $(this).detach().prependTo('#l1');  
 });
```

trouble is that after an element has been moved once it can be moved back to the original list.

I was hoping to use this as some kind of team selector so expect numerous changes to be made with items being added and removed a number of times.

thanks in advance Rob

Comment: cant understand your problem.! please explain more.

Comment: I don't see a question here. What is your question?

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/qFLqG/?

Comment: I want to be able to move list items to a different list and then possibly back to the same list, currently once a list item is moved from l1 to l2 if you try to move the list item back to l1 it just re-adds itself to l2.

Comment: Are you trying to do something like this? http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am NOT SURE if this will help, but I would try to define events like this:

```
$('body').on('click', '#l1 li',function(e){
//do the detach baby
});
```

etc...

In my opinion: my code is using [JQuery live event](http://api.jquery.com/live/). 
If you want to do it your way you should refresh event click definition after every prepend/append.